# Counting every user input?

Tags: java, android

I have to make an app that counts every time the user touches the screen, even outside the app, while its running. Ive already tried using the onTouch event, but that doesnt work outside the app.

```
package com.example.megegy;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public int counter=0;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int index = event.getActionIndex();
        int action = event.getActionMasked();
        int pointerId = event.getPointerId(index);

        if(action==1)
        {
            ++counter;
            Log.d("","Counted:"+counter);
            return true;

        }
        else return false;

    }

}
```

How can i count every single touch? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Registering user taps on a screen with no foreground activity sounds like a security risk to me. You could easily modify it to steal passwords and other sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

MotionEvent provides states of touch event, you can catch like this:

```
switch (event.getAction()) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          //calls when a finger first touches the screen
          break;

      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          //Finger is moving on screen
          break;

      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
          //Finger is gone up from screen
          break;
 }
```